# Can a set $A$ have exactly $2000$ subsets that are subsets of neither $B$, nor $C$?

Tags: combinatorics

> Can a set $A$ have exactly $2000$ subsets that are subsets of neither $B$, nor $C$?

So I was trying to solve this problem, but I don't even know where to start. I have tried to find some patterns by making few examples, but the only one I've got is that the number of such type of subsets is always even, but that's pretty much it.

Comment: You should provide more information about the question... What is $A, B,$ and $C$ ?? How do they look like ??

Comment: The answer is not always even, e.g., $A=\{1,2,3\}$, $B=\{1,2\}$, $C=\{3\}$.

Comment: @AnikBhowmick if there would be more information I would obviously provide it. But that's the whole problem.

Comment: @David, Subsets that A has that B and C don't are {2,3}; {1,3}, which is an even number

Comment: And $\{1,2,3\}$, making it odd.

Comment: @David, oh yes, I'm sorry, my mistake

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose that $B$ and $C$ are both subsets of $A$, that the number of elements in $A,B,C$ are $a,b,c$ respectively and that the number of elements in $B\cap C$ is $i$.  Then the number of admissible subsets is
$$2^a-2^b-2^c+2^i\ ,$$
and we want to know if this can equal $2000$.  The equation can be rewritten
$$2^a+2^i+2^5+2^4=2^b+2^c+2^{11}\ .$$
Now if the LHS is a sum of four *different* powers of $2$, then it cannot be written as a sum of three powers of $2$.  So two (at least) of $a,i,5,4$ must be equal, and it doesn't take much trial and error to find the solution
$$a=11\,,\ b=5\,,\ c=5\,,\ i=4\,.$$
So an example would be
$$A=\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11\}\,,\quad B=\{1,2,3,4,5\}\,,\quad C=\{2,3,4,5,6\}\,.$$

---

Checking this, to get a subset of $A$ which is a subset neither of $B$ nor of $C$, we need

- a non-empty subset of $\{7,8,9,10,11\}$ together with any subset of $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$: there are $(2^5-1)2^6$ possibilities; or
- a subset of $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ which includes both $1$ and $6$: there are $2^4$ possibilities.

Total, $31\times64+16=2000$.

Comment: Wow, thank you so much!

Comment: How did you do the equation rewriting? where did 4, 5, 11 come from

Comment: @qwr Hint: $2000$ is $2^{11}$ minus a bit.  Give it a try.

Comment: I am working through your answer and I understood everything except the main part, could you please explain how you derive the $2^a−2^b−2^c+2^i$ ?

Comment: I hope I did not make any mistakes, but: if we take sets $ A = \{1,2,3\} ,
 B = \{6, 7, 8\} $ and $C = \{3, 5\}$ then number of the subsets of A that are not subset of B and C according to this formula is $2^3 - 2^3 - 2^2 + 2^0$ ?

Comment: I worked with a few examples and I came up with this equation, what do you think about it $2^{|A|} - 2^{|A\cap{(B\cup{C})}|}$ ?

Comment: *expression, not equation

Comment: @Arci In answer to your first comment, use [inclusion/exclusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle).  Take the number of subsets of $A$, subtract the number of subsets of $B$, subtract the number of subsets of $C$.  Now subsets of $B\cap C$ have been subtracted twice, so add them back once.